# how to set activeLinkOptions for nb-route-tabset/ngx-admin

Tags: angular, angular8, ngx-admin

I would like tabs to be highlighted for multiple links. I'm not sure if I misunderstood the functionality. following is my code.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <nb-card size="small">
      <nb-route-tabset [tabs]="tabs" fullWidth activeLinkOptions="{exact:
    false}"></nb-route-tabset>
    </nb-card>
 </div>
</div>
```

My component:

```
  tabs: any[] = [
  {
    title: 'Contacts',
    route: '/addressbook/contact',
    icon: 'person-outline',
    responsive: true, 
  },
  {
    title: 'Companies',
    route: '/addressbook/company',
    icon: 'people-outline',
    responsive: true, 

  },
  {
    title: 'Company Types',
    route: '/addressbook/companytype/index',
    icon: 'grid-outline',
    responsive: true, 
  },
];
```

Rendered html:

```
<li _ngcontent-eap-c56="" class="route-tab responsive ng-star-inserted" routerlinkactive="active" tabindex="0" ng-reflect-router-link="/addressbook/companytype/index" ng-reflect-router-link-active-options="{exact:
    false}" ng-reflect-router-link-active="active">
```

I was hoping that "Company Types" tab would be highlighted whenever I visit "/addressbook/companytype/create" as well. is this the expected behavior with "exact:false"?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could add a path in your Angular router to do a redirect to the appropriate tab url.

Comment: I can navigate to both paths without an issue. i.e. '/addressbook/companytype/index' and '/addressbook/companytype/create'. but "Company Types" tab gets highlighted only when I navigate to '/addressbook/companytype/index'. My understading was that it should be highlighted for both paths by setting "exact:false". ??

Comment: The way your routing is setup could affect this. Can you put together a stackblitz of the basic routing you have setup.  Nebular has a stackblitz seed https://stackblitz.com/github/akveo/nebular-seed

Comment: Thank you! the code in your question was enough to solve my problem :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jason's comment above to try it on stackblitz helped me to understand the usage of activeLinkOptions. My two URLs are as follows.

> "/addressbook/companytype/Index" - Parent
>   "/addressbook/companytype/create" - Child

As you can see the child is not inherited from the parent. so it didn't work. now changed the URLs to look like below which worked well.

> "/addressbook/companytype" - Parent
>   "/addressbook/companytype/create" - Child